# Recommended Xbox 360 Video Format?

Tags: video, streaming, format, video-streaming, xbox360

What is the recommended or native video format for the Xbox 360? I have a Plex DLNA server setup and I dont want it to have to convert on the fly.

So what is the recommended Xbox 360 video playback format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [Video Playback FAQ - Xbox Engineering MSDN Blogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/xboxteam/december-2007-video-playback-faq)

Xbox 360 supports the following:

> **AVI**
>
> - File Extensions: .avi, .divx
> - Containers: AVI
> - Video Profiles: MPEG-4 Part 2, Simple & Advanced Simple Profile
> - Video Bitrate: 5 Mbps with resolutions of 1280 x 720 at 30fps.
> - Audio Profiles: Dolby® Digital 2 channel and 5.1 channel, MP3
> - Audio Max Bitrate: No restrictions.
>
> **H.264**
>
> - File Extensions: .mp4, .m4v, mp4v, .mov
> - Containers: MPEG-4, QuickTime
> - Video Profiles: Baseline, main, and high (up to Level 4.1) profiles.
> - Video Bitrate: 10 Mbps with resolutions of 1920 x 1080 at 30fps.
> - Audio Profiles: 2 channel AAC low complexity (LC)
> - Audio Max Bitrate: No restrictions.
>
> **MPEG-4**
>
> - File Extensions: .mp4, .m4v, .mp4v, .mov
> - Containers: MPEG-4, QuickTime
> - Video Profiles: Simple & Advanced Simple Profile
> - Video Bitrate: 5 Mbps with resolutions of 1280 x 720 at 30fps.
> - Audio Profiles: 2 channel AAC low complexity (LC)
> - Audio Max Bitrate: No restrictions.
>
> **WMV**
>
> - File Extensions: .wmv
> - Container: asf
> - Video Profiles: WMV7 (WMV1), WMV8 (WMV2), WMV9 (WMV3), VC-1 (WVC1 or WMVA) in simple, main, and advanced up to Level 3
> - Video Bitrate: 15 Mbps with resolutions of 1920 x 1080 at 30fps.
> - Audio Profiles: WMA7/8, WMA 9 Pro (stereo and 5.1), WMA lossless
> - Audio Max Bitrate: No restrictions.

Comment: To add further clarity, the recommended format is H.264 in the MP4 container. This format is also most likely to work on most devices.

Answer (score -1):

WMV and AVI would be the best way to go. H264 is not very trusting to me and you need Windows 7 version of Windows Media Center to play H264 videos properly (if not played through USB), let alone every codec except for WMV is limited to 4GB in a single file. Microsoft wanted to promote WMV by lowering other codecs to there worst since they actually believed that WMV would be the future codec but H264 ended up winning for Blu ray success because Microsoft stopped updating the WMV codec for anything new like dinamic ranges and HDR and stuff like that.